# Alternating series, even terms, factorial, boundedness

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I need to determine whether there exists $M>0$ such that $$| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x_{2n}}{\sqrt{n!}}| \le M \sqrt{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|^2}$$

$\{x_n\} \in \mathcal{l}^2, \ \ x_n \in \mathbb{K}$

I don't know what to use here.

Could you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, you will find that a suitable choice for $M$ is $$M = \sqrt{\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}} = \sqrt{e}$$